# Generate a random square texture from color input

Tags: texturing, node-editor, procedural

I have defined a color palette using the ColorRamp node, and I would like to generate a random texture with those colors. What is the best way of doing this?

I'm new to blender, so please explain like I'm five years old.

Here's what I have:

[image: Here's my input]

Here's what I want:

[image: Here's the output I want]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get good results with a single *Voronoi Texture*

1. Set Randomness to 0
2. Plug the Color Output to your ColorRamp
3. Set ColorRamp to linear (since the edges are already defined)

[image]

---

Edit:

To keep the corner aligned: offset and scale the texture using The Mapping Node

[image]

Or offset the UV coordinates by 1 / ( 2 * scale)
Thanks to @Gorgious for providing the formula.

[image]

Comment: Can confirm that this works! Follow up question: how do I get the same pixel size on all sides of my cube? [It looks like this right now](https://imgur.com/s2JkZFa)

Comment: You need to apply the scale of your object  (Object > Apply > Scale) and UV-unwrap it (in edit mode, with all faces selected, go to UV > Smart UV Project)

Comment: Is it possible to offset the bottom left corner here? https://i.stack.imgur.com/szvhy.gif

Comment: This could be a different question but : Offset the uv coordinates by 1 / ( 2 * scale) to get a voronoi texture with the botright corner of a square at 0, 0, 0. https://imgur.com/a/0P7YRMw

Comment: @Gorgious I found that you can simply scale it using the Mapping node, and it keeps the offset. But thanks anyway, I couldn't pinpoint the relation between scale and offset :).

Comment: I would set the color ramp to linear for a set color palette though. you still get different and mixed values in between. It kinda works in this example but if you have different hues i really shows.

Comment: @JachymMichal Oh right, that is simpler indeed :)